# Given a 16-bit integer, compare each of the four bits and output the maximum one

Tags: binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

. e.g. 0xFE10, should output 0xF(1111 in binary).

This is a Qualcomm interview question. This is my idea so far:

I am calling the 16-bit integer:

```
int num = /*whatever the number is*/
```

Have four bit masks:

```
int zeroTo4 = (num & 0x000F);  
int fiveTo5 = (num & 0x00F0) >> 4;   
int eightTo12 = (num & 0x0F00) >> 8;   
int twelveTo16 = (num & 0xF000) >> 12;   

int printbit = zeroTo4;

if( fiveTo5 > printbit )
    printbit = fiveTo5;

if( eightTo12 > printbit )
    printbit = eightTo12;

if( twelveTo16 > printbit )
    printbit = twelveTo16;

printf( "Largest bit of %X is %1X\n", num, printbit );
```

However, I'm pretty sure there's a simpler and easier way to do this. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int max4(int j)
{
   int ret=0;
   while(j>0)
   {
        if( (j&0xf) > ret ) ret=j&0xf;
        j>>=4;
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Some may prefer:

```
int max4(int j)
{
   int ret=0;
   do if( (j&0xf) > ret ) ret=j&0xf;
   while((j>>=4)>0);
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Since `int` is a signed quantity, this will fail if `j < 0`.

Comment: Couldn't that corner case be solved by changing the while condition from `j > 0` to `while( j != 0 )`?

Comment: @lordmarinara: Not necessarily, because right shifting a signed quantity does *sign extension*, meaning repeatedly doing that will never reach zero.

Comment: I suppose I could do the opposite logic:

`int ret = 0;

while( j != 0 )
{
    if( (j & 0xF000) > ret ) ret = j & 0xF000;
    j <<= 4;
}
return ( ret >> 12 ) & 0x000F;`

If I remember correctly, a left shit does not preserve the sign bit when shifting.

Comment: We're given that the input is a 16-bit integer. So it can't be less than zero when represented in 32 bits.

Comment: Just use `unsigned int` to avoid undefined behaviour.